# Chasing referrals in Ldap

Tags: ldap, openldap

I'm currently improving a program featuring an ldap integration. This ldap integration is currently not able to handle ldap referrals.

I do understand, that i will gen entries back that will hold the URL to the referred domain controller, the port and the baseDN.

My question is:

For my searches to the ldap directory i do a bind of my main (root) ldap directory. What do i need to do know, when i come across one of those referral entries?

- Do i need a new bind to the server referred to?
- If so, is it neccessary, that the username and password i used for the root system will also work for the subsystem? Otherwise, i wouldn't be able to connect to it?
- Is there an easier way to tell an ldap search to chase referrals on its own?

I'm using the openLdap client for my searches through the ldap.

Comment: This is really off topic. Should be migrated to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

> Do i need a new bind to the server referred to?

Yes.

> If so, is it neccessary, that the username and password i used for the root system will also work for the subsystem?

No.

> Is there an easier way to tell an ldap search to chase referrals on its own?

There are various OpenLDAP slave replication configuration options about that. Depending on the LDAP API you use you may be able to enable referral-chasing automatically, as for example you can in Java JNDI.

Comment: In specific example, openldap's ldap backend ( http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/backends.html#LDAP ) will chase referrals by default on your behalf.